# Java spring transaction could not rollback Invalid state, the Connection object is closed

Tags: java, spring, sql-server-2008, spring-transactions

Java spring with Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (X64) Nov 24 2008 16:17:31 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

I am using a transaction manager as follows which usually works very well

```
  <tx:advice id="TxAdvice" transaction-manager="TransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="java.lang.Throwable"/>
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>

  <aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.rdc.*.*Dao.*(..))" advice-ref="TxAdvice"/>
  </aop:config>
```

But i found unusual situation while executing following method on line 2 database lock occurs and sqlserver 2008 generated database lock time out and statement 1 record become permanent instead of rollback data ? and generate exception

```
public void linkDao(){
insert(); // 1
update(); // 2
delete(); // 3
}


StackTrace: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JDBC transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:279)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:800)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:339)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lot of investigation possibly this issue is b/c of Sqlserver went out of memory.

i tried this command to free up some momeory

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE (‘ALL’) WITH MARK_IN_USE_FOR_REMOVAL;
```